# How do I split this string back into a list? Using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am saving a list of strings to save to shared preferences but as I must save the list as a string, I am really struggling to split the string back into the list.
My Strings:

```
"Wellington, NZ"
"Sydney, AU"
"Melbourne, AU"
```

I save this in shared preferences as `"Wellington, NZ, Sydney, AU, Melbourne AU"`
How can i split the string back to a list? I cant use string.split(",") as it'll split at every `","` and I have also tried using regex bug have had no luck.

given my string in shared preferences is:

```
val stringToSplit = "Wellington, NZ, Sydney, AU, Melbourne AU"
```

I need to split this back into a list that looks like this:

```
val listOfPlaces = ["Wellington, NZ",
                    "Sydney, AU",
                    "Melbourne, AU"]
```

Comment: Why you cannot use the stringList api from prefs? But if your 100% sure that all items contain commas in them, probably you can try yo split after each 2 commas.

Comment: ooh i did not know you could save sets in shared preferences!

Comment: I'm on phone and it's hard to write an answer with it, but you can also provide the answer and accept it. I guess it would also give you a badge (I'm saying it bc I think you're a new joiner)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chuncked` with `split` to achieve that

```
val stringToSplit = "Wellington, NZ, Sydney, AU, Melbourne AU"
val splits = stringToSplit.split(",")
val result = splits.chunked(splits.size / 2).map { it.joinToString(",") }
result.forEach { print(it) }
```

Comment: Ah awesome yeah this is a good solution, thank you! However I discovered I can save my Arraylist of strings as a HashSet in sharedpreferences so i no longer need to convert the list to string and back to list again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to append a new string that combines the previous ie:

```
string1= "Washington, WA"
string2= "Alaska, AK"
string3= "Montana, MT"
string4 = []
string4.append(string1)
string4.append(string2)
string4.append(string3)

print(string4)
```

which prints:

```
['Washington, WA', 'Alaska, AK', 'Montana, MT']
```

You could split them first too if you need the city and state as their own elements.

Comment: How can you go from "'Washington, WA', 'Alaska, AK', 'Montana, MT'" back to 3 individual strings? Thats my question

Comment: Oh that's my mistake....I believe you can use np.array_split()

Comment: Such as:

split_this = np.array_split(string4, len(string4))

Which divides the list by its length so it will split each element of the list into its own array

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, but maybe i havent explained clearly enough on what im trying to do... I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
val s = "a,b,c,d,e"
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")))
```

you will get the list of string